# The space $M_g$ with the complex structure induced from $T_g$ is a coarse moduli space for compact Riemann surfaces of genus $g$

Tags: moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces, coarse-moduli-spaces

Proposition: The space $M_g$ with the complex structure induced from $T_g$ is a coarse moduli space for compact Riemann surfaces of genus $g$.

[image]

In the proof of (1), I wonder why the holomorphic map $\tilde{f}: \tilde{B}\to T_g$ which is equivariant with respect to a homomorphism $\pi_1(B)\to \text{Mod}_g$?

Resourse:https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/iccm/2015/0003/0002/ICCM-2015-0003-0002-a005.pdf

Comment: The equivariance condition can be expressed in terms of a commutative diagram involving the map $\tilde{f}$. Using the universal property of the fine moduli space $\mathcal T_g$, you can express this condition as a condition involving the map $\tilde{\pi}$. What is this condition? Can you check it?

Comment: @WillSawin Can you be more precise? I can only see, by the universal property, there is a family of curves of genus $g$: $\phi:u\to T_g$, s.t. $\tilde{\pi}:X'\to \tilde{B}$ is the pullback of $\tilde{f}:\tilde{B}\to T_g$ along $\phi:u\to T_g$. I don't see the relation with $\pi_1(B)\to\text{Mod}_g$.

Comment: Suppose you have a homomorphism $\pi_1(B) \to \operatorname{Mod}_g$. What does it mean for  $\tilde{f}$ to be equivariant with respect to this homomorphism?

Comment: @WillSawin My understanding is we have an induces holomorphic map of $\tilde{f}$, $B=\tilde{B}/\pi_1(B)\to T_g/\text{Mod}_g=M_g$. I still can't get your point...

Comment: By definition, a map is equivariant with respect to $h: \pi_1(B) \to \operatorname{Mod}_g$, if and only if, for any element $\sigma$ of $\pi_1(B)$, $\tilde{f} \circ \sigma = h(\sigma) \circ \tilde{f}$. Here we let $\sigma$ act on $\tilde{B}$ by the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $\tilde{B}$ and similarly with $h(\sigma)$ acting on $ T_g$. Is that definition familiar to you?

Comment: This is an equality of two maps $\tilde{B} \to T_g$. By pullback, these maps define two families of Riemann surfaces with markings over $\tilde{B}$. What are those families? Because $T_g$ is a fine moduli space, the maps are equal if and only if the families are isomorphic by a map preserving these markings. Can you check this?